# Can you build a maven project with code only with java?

Tags: java, maven, build

I wanted to ask, if its possible to build a maven project with just code. So I mean i run a application, select a Project, and it automatically build the maven project, without pressing anything in the Project itself.

I didnt find anything in the web, so hopefully it even works.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand. You want to write a program that runs Maven on a Java project?

Comment: Exactly, a Application/Program where u say the location of the Project and it builds the project with maven.

Comment: To build a project you usually need to run something like `mvn clean install` on the project. So your Application needs to start a new bash/cmd process that runs the Maven command.

Comment: And how can I do something like that? Don't really have much experience with maven...

Comment: You can run Maven like any other command line tool. In e.g. Java you would probably use a Process and start Maven with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to automate the build process, maybe you should use jenkins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).